# Customizing redmine issue entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, customization, redmine

Well, the powers that be would like Redmine to be aware of the data in one of our other systems so issues can be auto assigned to staff based on our business application's parcel id's.

Until now we had a call tracking system written from scratch. I'd like to bastardize Redmine since it comes so close to meeting all user requirements. I think if I get pointed in the right direction I can hook into Redmine some already written javascript and already existing webservices to pull the necessary data to display it on a Redmine ticket at the time of ticket creation. I know that Redmine is highly customizable, but I don't know where to begin. I already checked for existing plugins to do this and I found none.  [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly.
You want to insert some code to a new field `Parcel ID` on Issue Form and it should set some value to Assignee select.

some question to clarify details:
- What relationship between ParcelID and Assignee (User in Redmine)? One-to-one or more complicated?

- if Assignee is set should inserting ParcelID override this value?

- (vice versa) If ParcelID is set then it should set up Assignee. Can Assignee be changed after this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you want.

1. You can add custom_field or write a migration to add a new column to table `issues` and patch issue form (you can use redmine hooks http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Hooks_List). I prefer second way because it does not depend on Redmine settings.
2. You should add in plugin a route and method into `issues_controller`. This action will get AJAX request with ParcelID from the view (issue form) and proxy it to external server. The response should be user email (I think only this info is common for users in Redmine and External server). The action should find appropriate user in Redmine and return user_id to the view.
3. Patch issue form: add new input `Parcel ID` and add JS code. JS code should send AJAX after ParcelID loses focus and setup `Assignee` if request returns user_id.

---

some notes:

- I don't think that you will manage to communicate with external server directly (without controller)  because Server can return own user_id or user_email but view will not manage to setup Assignee using this attributes.
- I think it is necessary to care about performance because JS code will start at least two requests (View<->Redmine, Redmine<->External Server)

hope it helps you